# Argument of type 'HttpClient' is n ot assignable to parameter of type 'HttpClient' (angular migration v4 to v5)

Tags: angular, angular5

I am tried to update my angular application (v4) to angular 5, in my application i have ngx-admin-lte package in node_modules, I am still have this last error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/ngx-admin-lte/src/ngx-admin-lte.module.ts(12,37): 
error TS2345: Argument of type 'HttpClient' is not assignable to parameter
of type 'HttpClient'.Types have separate declarations of a private property
'handler'.
```

In my ngx-admin-lte.module.ts I changed:

```
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
...
export function createTranslateLoader( http: Http ) {
return new TranslateHttpLoader( http, '../public/assets/i18n', '.json' );
} 
// imports
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule,
RouterModule,
ToasterModule,
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    deps: [Http],
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: (createTranslateLoader)
}}),
],
```

And the http-loader.d.ts file which is called by TranslateHttpLoader method in ngx-admin-lte.module.ts

```
// http-loader.d.ts
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { TranslateLoader } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
export declare class TranslateHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {
private http;
private prefix;
private suffix;
constructor(http: Http, prefix?: string, suffix?: string);
/**
 * Gets the translations from the server
 * @param lang
 * @returns {any}
 */
getTranslation(lang: string): any;
}
```

into:

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
export function createTranslateLoader( http: HttpClient ) {
return new TranslateHttpLoader( http, '../public/assets/i18n', '.json' );
}
//imports
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule,
RouterModule,
ToasterModule,
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    deps: [HttpClient],
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: (createTranslateLoader)
}}),
],

//http-loader.d.ts
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { TranslateLoader } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
export declare class TranslateHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {
private http;
private prefix;
private suffix;
constructor(http: HttpClient, prefix?: string, suffix?: string);
/**
 * Gets the translations from the server
 * @param lang
 * @returns {any}
 */
getTranslation(lang: string): any;
}
```

but still have the error mentioned above when i try to compile, and this error comes from the function:

```
export function createTranslateLoader( http: HttpClient ) {
return new TranslateHttpLoader( http, '../public/assets/i18n', '.json' );
}
```

and i can not understand where is the error.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you changing the typing file directly (.d.ts)? Why dont you update the dependency that provides you that type?

Comment: Thanks Jota, how I can update the dependency (ng update ?)